# How can I avoid having multiple classes for something just for different versions of an API?

Tags: c#

I want to target 2 versions of APIs which are 98% similar. For now, I write 2 identical classes with the same code that each of their references to one of the APIs. Is there any better way to do this? I mean it is not a smart way to have 2 classes with 98 percent identical. I searched a lot but I don't know what keyboard should I use. Interfaces can not be used because the objects which will be passed to the methods are different.

Here is the V19 code:

```
public class CSISAPV19
{
    private readonly SAP2000v19.cSapModel SapModel;
    private readonly SAP2000v19.cOAPI SAPObject;

    public CSISAPV19(SAP2000v19.cSapModel SapModel, SAP2000v19.cOAPI SAPObject)
    {
        this.SapModel = SapModel;
        this.SAPObject = SAPObject;
    }

    public int GetLoadPatterns()
    {
       return SapModel.LoadPatterns.GetNameList(ref count, ref loadPatternNames);
    }
}
```

And the V1

```
public class CSISAPV1
{
    private readonly SAP2000v1.cSapModel SapModel;
    private readonly SAP2000v1.cOAPI SAPObject;

    public CSISAPV1(SAP2000v1.cSapModel SapModel, SAP2000v1.cOAPI SAPObject)
    {
        this.SapModel = SapModel;
        this.SAPObject = SAPObject;
    }

    public int GetLoadPatterns()
    {
        return SapModel.LoadPatterns.GetNameList(ref count, ref loadPatternNames);
    }
}
```

`cSapModel` is an interface that they have nothing to share in these two revisions.
`SAP2000v19.cSapModel` and `SAP2000v1.cSapModel` are 98% identical but they are created individually and independently.

Comment: You should _really_ stick to the standard [naming conventions](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md). For starter, `cSapModel` should never be a name of an interface.

Comment: this is not created by me. this is API from the "www.csiamerica.com" company that I'm using.

Comment: How many of these SAP2000v19 vs. SAP2000v1 types/interfaces will you have to deal with? Are the signatures of the methods and properties declared in these types/interfaces compatible/equivalent between SAP2000v19 and SAP2000v1?

Comment: Just 4 or 5. but they have lots of methods. they are quite similar classes.

Comment: And are the signatures of these methods compatible/equivalent with each other between the different SAP2000 API versions?

Comment: yes. they have equivalent signatures.

Comment: Then i would suggest to create an (abstract) base class that does not depend on the SAP2000 APIs itself but declares abstract methods that represent SAP2000-specific  functionality. (whether it would be better to have individual SAP2000 methods be represented by an abstract method, or whether an abstract method would represent a piece of logic involving multiple SAP2000 method calls is for you to decide) Then derive two classes from this common base class which will implement the abstract methods using the respective SAP2000v19 or SAP2000v1 functions.

Comment: (1/2) Another possibility (which i personally find horrendous, because it replaces compile-time checks with runtime checks, which can become a maintenance nightmare) is to stuff the cSapModel and cOAPI instances in `dynamic` variables and access the respective methods/properties of those instances **only** through these dynamic variables. Having dynamic variables leads to the binding of the respective methods/properties being done "late" during execution (think of it doing reflection at runtime to figure out the actual method/property to be called).

Comment: (2/2) If your code then only uses these `dynamic` variables, it becomes independent of the actual SAP2000v1/SAP2000v19 types, and thus you can avoid code duplication. But as said, i find this normally a bad idea, because if you by accident mistype a method name, provide the wrong number of parameters or parameters of a wrong type, the compiler won't notice that error, and you'll notice it only when your code is executing and attempting to call that method with the mistyped name or with mismatched parameters...

Comment: Can't you have a variable or two and pass in the right value from elsewhere based on the version of the API?